# Number of autoregulation and FFL motifs in a network

Tags: bioinformatics, transcription-factor

Suppose we have a network with **N*** nodes (N* is the number of internal nodes). Every directed link in this network exists with probability **p**. What would be the number of:

1. motifs that are auto-regulatory?
2. feed-forward loop motifs
3. feed-back loop motifs

Comment: that looks like a homework problem. please see http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework on how to modify your question

Comment: Yes it was a homework problem. Thank you for the link. I am new in the whole stackexchange thing. I read it's ok that I answer my question though, now that I know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The average number of auto-regulatory motifs (self-edges), is equal to the number of edges **E** times the probability that an edge is a self-edge which is $p_{self}=1/N$, with **N** being the total number of nodes. Therefore, $<N_{self}>_{rand} \approx E/N$
2. & 3. According to U.Alon's book (["Introduction to Systems Biology"](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/mcb/UriAlon/introduction-systems-biology-design-principles-biological-circuits)), the mean number of times that a subgraph G occurs in a random network is given by the following formula: $<N_G>\approx a^{-1}N^n p^g$.

Explaining what each term of the formula means:

- **α**: is a number that includes combinatorial factors related to the structure and symmetry of each subgraph, equal to 1 for feed-forward loop (FFL) and equal to 3 for feed-back loop (FBL)
- $N^n$: is the number of ways of choosing a set of **n** nodes out of **N**. Because there are N ways of choosing the first one, times N-1$\approx$N ways of choosing the second one, and so on..(this approximation is true for large networks)
- $p^g$ : is the probability to get the g edges in the appropriate places (each with probability p)